# Is JTAG the standard way to program ARM processors?

Tags: microcontroller, arm, microprocessor, flash, jtag

Some electrical engineer once told me, that each ARM M3 processor can be flashed the same way, no matter which manufacturer it came from.

I suppose he meant using JTAG, or is there another way?

Btw, I'm meaning to flash an empty ARM processor without a bootloader.

Comment: ARM-based micros are flashed over JTAG or SWD.  Some will accept programming over either protocol, while others require one or the other.  For example, the Nordic Semiconductor nRF52 is SWD only.  And just because all M3s can be flashed the same way does not mean software is freely interchangeable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I suppose he meant using JTAG, or is there another way?

Probably he didn't. ARM has their own debugging bus standard – SWD (single wire debug), that is very well-specified. JTAG, on the other hand, is merely a electrical and shift-register-level standard, and it's up to device manufacturers to give JTAG endpoints and actions a meaning.

SWD programmers can be had for <5€. Look for products called "STLink v2  compatible" or so. The ST in the name stems from the fact that they are based on the protocol that STmicro USB-to-SWD adapters speak between host computer and adapter, but since they only "transport" SWD, they work with every SWD-compatible microcontroller.

On most development systems, you'd want to use OpenOCD as "driver" for these devices, so that you can easily flash images (either directly through OpenOCD or using e.g. GDB's `load`). If you're stuck with an absurd OS that needs specific drivers even for generic devices, you'd probably have to install ST's tools.

> Btw, I'm meaning to flash an empty ARM processor without a bootloader.

Yep, sounds like a classical case for SWD – ARM offers hardware for that in their cores, and most manufacturers choose to use that and assign pins.

Also note that most manufacturers (including ST) ship their "empty" ICs with some kind of bootloader, over which you can load firmware through a serial port or even USB into the device – suuuuper handy for manufacturing.

For a bit of discussion on SWD, I actually *recommend* (for the pure fun it is to read) [PoC||GTFO 0x10, pp. 26](https://www.alchemistowl.org/pocorgtfo/), which begins with an introduction of ARM's debugging infrastructure and SWD as a protocol, and then goes on to explain how to use SWD-connected ARMs as sophisticated IO expanders rather than independent MCUs.

Comment: So you can use SWD to flash your program to the processor? I thought it was only for debugging.

Comment: If production programming via JTAG or SWD, there are devices that support multiple loads at once for greater throughput.  Example: https://www.elprotronic.com/products?show&id=55. Also, many (most? all?) devices support a serial code upload via USB, UART or whatever the chip manufacturer chooses.  This is usually code loading only and no debugging.  For most of my products, it's JTAG/SWD for development and then serial update in the production environment, and sometimes getting code pre-loaded by the chip distributor (which is usually serial).

Comment: Programming MCU flash memories over SWD is *not* actually standardized - the details differ for each vendor, and to a degree each chip.  Often what you end up doing is writing a buffer of data, writing a tiny program to a another location in RAM, and then executing that little program, which does the actual flash memory writes.  Or other times you invoke such code that is built into the factory ROM (that may also provide bootloader functionality).  Typically you can accomplish the same things via JTAG extensions - SWD is basically a simplification of JTAG.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I'd like to agree on the part that flash programming isn't actually standardized, but mainly in the aspect that flash isn't always mapped to the same address space on AHB. It's a very "ARM" thing to have all the peripherals just dangle around in the memory space, and so I know of no vendor that doesn't also attach its flash to the normal memory space you can access on the SWD AHB access port. To agree with you some more: You often have to enable flash writes before you can erase/overwrite flash banks, however.

Comment: Note that OpenOCD has a lot of scripts that already represent different ICs and specify where the flash memory is, and how to access it, so that you just have to specify the image file name: http://openocd.org/doc-release/html/Flash-Programming.html#Flash-Programming

Comment: @MarcusMüller - it's not just the address that changes, the actual procedure for valid programming is device unique - sometimes it is published, other times it is "we aren't going to even tell you how, you have to invoke our ROM routine".  Not uncommonly there are additional details, for example Atmel SAM series can have fuse bits that have to be set to enable booting from flash, and can optionally swap the addressing of the flash banks.  Yes, openocd encapsulates these things, but the point is there are details *to* encapsulate, I've had to patch it for uniqueness within a supported family.

Comment: @ChrisStratton exactly! You're absolutely right; the important fact here is that flash is a vendor-specific peripheral to the ARM core, and you need to consult with your vendor on how to use that.

Comment: Wow, that PoC||GTFO is really quite amazing!

Comment: Well, it proves a concept. Otherwise, it would have to GTFO.

Comment: So to recapitulate everything, there is NO universal device to flash any ARM processor?

If I have an M3 from one manufacturer and another from a different manufacturer, then both may have different ways to be flashed?

Comment: @user41666 more complicated than that: you can use an SWD interface to "talk" to half of the chips, JTAG for the other half, but neither interface specifies what to "say" to program the flash. But I consider that merely a detail – you couldn't run firmware for one chip unmodified on the other